# Animation effects with css and/or Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Is there any Jquery plugin or CSS code to have effects like in the following page
http://engineer.org.in/2013/ and http://engineer.org.in/2013/#Comps (With out using webGL)...

Comment: Yes, this could be done using CSS and jQuery.

Comment: Can you help me with the css code or jquery plugin name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading page?? Its just a gif image with jquery code

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
</script>
```

Read this [link](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/show-loading-image-while-page-is.html)

After the loading event you have a transition event. You can do this just using css3 Transitions and Tranforms

In this case we are using left and scaling property. Imagine you have a cube class:

```
transEx {
    background-color: #066882;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 3s;
    -o-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.cude:hover {
    background-color: #FC8F30;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transform: translate(900px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(900px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(900px, 0);
    transform: translate(900px, 0);
}
```

See my [example here!](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/cTrMs/)

I recommend follow a [css3 Transitions Tutorial](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/)

In other hand you can use Jquery library. Just focus on [effects category](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). In this link you can see a lot of examples.

Comment: Not the loading effect...Wait till the site loads you will find some good animation...